# Does Case-Insensitive Deterministic Encryption support SOQL LIKE and STARTS WITH statements?

Tags: security, platform-encryption, shield-encryption, shield

The current Salesforce documentation states that deterministic encryption only supports exact, case-sensitive matches. This is why comparison operators that return partial matches aren't supported.

Will this also be the case with case-insensitive deterministic encryption which is currently in beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, case-insensitive deterministic encryption will still be exact-match, with the exception being that it is case insensitive.

For example, if you encrypt "John Whelan" with case-insensitive you could filter by "john whelan" and still get a match.   With case-sensitive you would have to filter by "John Whelan" to get a match.

In either case, filtering by "John", "Whelan" or any other partial text will result in no match.